# How can I get pug to render dynamic handlebars css class?

Tags: handlebars.js, pug

Here's the HTML I want:

```
<form class="{{cssClass}}" autocomplete="off">
  <img src="{{item.img}}" />
</form>
```

Here's what I get when I convert that to pug:

```
form.{{cssClass}}(autocomplete="off")
  img(src="{{item.img}}")
```

... but that is not valid pug syntax and will not parse back to html.

The question is what is the correct pug syntax to achieve this HTML output?

Comment: I'm confused. Don't Handlebars and Pug have the same purpose - compiling templates into JavaScript functions? Why would you need to use both of them?

Comment: They don't have quite the same purpose, although agreed there is overlap. Pug is an HTML precompiler, which also has templating. Handlebars provides templating for HTML markup. 

The issue here is 
1) I'm in an environment which forces the use of handlebars, 
2) I don't like HTML syntax. I must use handlebars (see 1.) but I want to use pug as a precompiler so I don't have to deal with HTML syntax.

Comment: @geoidesic I am wondering if you are using Foundry VTT -- I had the same question coming from Roll20 and using pug. I find the handlebars syntax overly verbose. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Pug. However, doing some quick Googling I found this [GitHub post](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2907#issuecomment-345294139) that says you can set a class using the attribute syntax (as you are doing with the image src) instead of the ".class" syntax.

A valid Pug template would be:

```
form(class="{{cssClass}}" autocomplete="off")
    img(src="{{item.img}}")
```

The [Pug documentation on Attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html) also demonstrates a class being applied this way.